# Pandoc Lua filter to prefix absolute paths of links and images

Tags: lua, pandoc

I [rewrote one of my Pandoc filters](https://github.com/musteresel/musteresel.github.io/blob/38d6e840c60010ace486f44946845ade0a6138e8/utils/prefix-path.lua) (initially written in [Haskell](https://github.com/musteresel/pandoc-project-relative-links), then [Python](https://github.com/musteresel/musteresel.github.io/blob/60b11762d3aa12c343cbf3b2060f20174bd29382/utils/project-rel-links/prl.py)) as a Lua Pandoc filter. I'd be happy to receive feedback on how this filter could be improved, especially in regards to best practices / clean code regarding Lua. I really dislike all the `type` calls in the `Meta` function.

```lua
pathPrefixMetaName = "pathToProjectRoot"

-- Global variable to store path prefix once it has been
-- extracted from the metadata
pathPrefix = nil

-- Traversal should run top down, in order for the
-- Meta function to be called before Link or Image
-- functions. Otherwise the path prefix is not known
-- when the Link/Image functions are run.
traverse = 'topdown'

-- Utility function with prepends paths with the path prefix
local function prefix_path(p)
    return pandoc.path.normalize(pathPrefix .. "/" .. p)
end

-- Adjust absolute link targets
function Link(l)
    if not pathPrefix then return end
    if pandoc.path.is_absolute(l.target) then
        local new_link = l:clone()
        new_link.target = prefix_path(l.target)
        return new_link
    end
end

-- Adjust absolute src links of images
function Image(i)
    if not pathPrefix then return end
    if pandoc.path.is_absolute(i.src) then
        local new_img = i:clone()
        new_img.src = prefix_path(i.src)
        return new_img
    end
end

-- Optimize traversal, stop if no meta variable available
function Blocks(p)
    if not pathPrefix then return nil, false end
end

-- Extract required meta variable
function Meta(m)
    local meta_var = m[pathPrefixMetaName]
    if not meta_var then return nil, false end
    if type(meta_var) == "string" then
        -- When specified via command line option -M, then
        -- the meta variable will be a bare string
        pathPrefix = meta_var
    elseif type(meta_var) == "table"
        and type(meta_var[1]) == "userdata"
        and pandoc.utils.type(meta_var[1]) == "Inline" then
        -- When specified via YAML, then the meta variable
        -- will be a pandoc [Str "path/"]
        pathPrefix = meta_var[1].text
    end
end
```

The goal of this filter is to transform absolute links / image src links by adding a prefix to them, like `this is [some link](/somewhere.html)` would result (with the prefix `../../`) into `this is [some link](../../somewhere.html)` (assuming conversion from and to markdown).

Comment: Running this filter works like this: `echo "This is [some link](/somewhere.html)" | pandoc -f markdown -t markdown --lua-filter prefix-path.lua -MpathToProjectRoot=../../` Documentation about pandoc lua filters is available [here](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html)